# Unable to install Azure SDK 2.6 for VS2013 using Web Platform Installer

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net, web-platform-installer

I am trying to install Azure SDK 2.6 for Visual Studio 2013. I tried downloading the Web Platform Installer from the archive page [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/archive-net-downloads/) . Here is the [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=534215). However each time I try to open the installer I am getting the following error - **"Microsoft Web Platform Installer couldn't find the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overriding your feed with a different feed."**.
A strange issue is that if I try to upgrade the Azure project from Visual Studio (2013), it's giving me an option to download Web Platform Installer to download SDK 2.6, but that Web Platform Installer is showing the options only for SDK v2.8.
Is Azure SDK 2.6 retired? Or is there a workaround to install SDK 2.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the URL link below, click on the **Download** button and you should be able to get the components for **Azure SDK 2.6**

[Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46892)

Answer (score -2):

you should still be able to install **Azure SDK 2.6 for Visual Studio 2013** from **Web Platform Installer** (WPI) as shown below.

[image]

Comment: That webpi entry won't install the complete SDK only part of it (may not be enough depending on the project).

@Pratik - the link from the archive page is [clearly] broken, I'm trying to track down the correct link...